# I have recieved a mail from my website mail, that my wordpress site was hacked?

Tags: wordpress

rom: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
PLEASE FORWARD THIS EMAIL TO SOMEONE IN YOUR COMPANY WHO IS ALLOWED TO MAKE IMPORTANT DECISIONS!

We have hacked your website and extracted your databases.

How did this happen?
Our team has found a vulnerability within your site that we were able to exploit. After finding the vulnerability we were able to get your database credentials and extract your entire database and move the information to an offshore server.

What does this mean?

We will systematically go through a series of steps of totally damaging your reputation. First your database will be leaked or sold to the highest bidder which they will use with whatever their intentions are. Next if there are e-mails found they will be e-mailed that their information has been sold or leaked and your was at fault thusly damaging your reputation and having angry customers/associates with whatever angry customers/associates do. Lastly any links that you have indexed in the search engines will be de-indexed based off of blackhat techniques that we used in the past to de-index our targets.

How do I stop this?

We are willing to refrain from destroying your site's reputation for a small fee. The current fee is $2000 USD in bitcoins (BTC).

Send the bitcoin to the following Bitcoin address (Copy and paste as it is case sensitive):

1Q1DF9rJS6fNDSpiV2iEA46BS1mNEaELtC

Once you have paid we will automatically get informed that it was your payment. Please note that you have to make payment within 5 days after receiving this notice or the database leak, e-mails dispatched, and de-index of your site WILL start!

How do I get Bitcoins?

You can easily buy bitcoins via several websites or even offline from a Bitcoin-ATM. We suggest you https://cex.io/ for buying bitcoins.

What if I don’t pay?

If you decide not to pay, we will start the attack at the indicated date and uphold it until you do, there’s no counter measure to this, you will only end up wasting more money trying to find a solution. We will completely destroy your reputation amongst google and your customers.

This is not a hoax, do not reply to this email, don’t try to reason or negotiate, we will not read any replies. Once you have paid we will stop what we were doing and you will never hear from us again!

Please note that Bitcoin is anonymous and no one will find out that you have complied.

Comment: You should change all of your passwords immediately (assuming you haven't done so already), then read this: [Help, I think I've been hacked - WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/).

Comment: It’s fake. They haven’t hacked anything. They have no way of knowing you’ve paid them their bitcoin as your transfer to them would be as anonymous as their account. Had the exact same email on some of our client accounts too, even one static site that didn’t have a DB!!

Answer (score -1):

Install the plugin "**Wordfence WordPress Security Plugin**" and do a full scan on the web files to check if there are any modifications done by the attacker, It is also good to check if you installed **BAD PLUGINS (NULLED Plugins)** from outside the Wordpress plugins directory.

Answer (score -1):

I think your function.php file is infected by a malfunction. Most of the time we use the third-party plugins or theme and we overlook the updates notifications and that's why our site is infected malfunction easily. So collect plugins or from the treated sources.

If you will able to access your website then follow this
Solution:
Open your theme function.php file by using any PHP editor, and check unexpected line fo code and remove those lines. And save.